# Failed to reenroll 'admin': Response from server: Error Code: 20 - Authentication failure

Tags: certificate, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, certificate-authority

I have a project based on hyperledger fabric. The problem now is that all the signing certificates of all identities are expired. Even the certificate authority tls-cert is expired, I removed the tls and restarted the Docker CA containers which regenerated the tls cert again.

But now: I want to re-enroll the current identities (admin, peers etc..), but I get an error which is as follows:

> Failed to reenroll 'admin': Response from server: Error Code: 20 - Authentication failure.

The command I used to enroll is as follows:

`fabric-ca-client reenroll -u https://aEdmin123:aEdmin123pw@localhost:1033 --caname ca-org --tls.certfiles ${PWD}/test/test3/fabric-ca/Org/tls-cert.pem`

What can I try next?

Comment: I guess you are using FabricCA to create the identities. Are you running the CA server in a container or natively? 
Please cross-checks the admin id and password.

Comment: In a conainer I am running the CA

Comment: As I recall, the reenroll command actually requires you to use existing identity crypto material and not username/password.  You can probably just leverage the `enroll` command here rather than `reenroll`.